# Count the number of times a submit button has been clicked

Tags: jquery

Is there a way I can tell how many times a form submit button has been clicked using jQuery? If so, can someone please provide a code sample? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy.

html:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#Submit").submit(function(){
             count++;
        });
});
```

Comment: You missed a space in your selector.

Comment: It's not required for "elementType:identifier" combinations (i.e. `("form#Submit")` or `("form.submit")`).

Comment: @Nathan: `#Submit` is an element in the form.  His code will not match anything.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking in terms of a form named submit, but yeah based on the html, that definitely won't work! :)

Comment: is there a way to do this without using global variable in jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

If you are posting the form to the server, you may find it easier, and more reliable, to track the form submissions from the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can increment a variable in the click or submit events.