# Count how many times button is clicked without using global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

Is there a way I can tell how many times a form submit button has been clicked using jQuery ?

I have found some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504070/count-the-number-of-times-a-submit-button-has-been-clicked) but I don't want to use a global variable.

Is there some way to achieve this without using global variable in jQuery ?

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#Submit").submit(function(){
             count++;
        });
});
```

just for example --> I want to allow user to click the button 4 times but if he click more than 4 times I will show some alert message

Comment: move the var count = 0; into the anonymous function.

Comment: I don't think so , because In all cases you have to use a variable to save the number of times Button is clicked .

Comment: it's all about scope ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so this is an edit on an answer to help you along

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form#Submit").submit(function () {
        var count = $(this).data("count") || 0;
        if(count >= x)
        {
            //user clicked more than you wanted to so do something here 
        }

        $(this).data("count", ++count);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could store the count in the button's `data`:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form#Submit").submit(function () {
            var count = $(this).data("count") || 0;
            $(this).data("count", ++count);
        });
    });
```

Comment: so if I want to prevent user from clicking that button multiple times for example 4 times user can click the button!!!.....so could you modify above code to allow user to only click 4 times

Comment: @hitesh: all you need to do is capture the $(this).date('count') cast it as an int and add an if block. you should try that on your own without a verbatim answer.

Comment: @workabyte - Thanks :) can you pls edit your code as you have explained !! so that i can understand better!!

Comment: @hitesh Stackoverflow != free code. also note that you should also check this on server side ;)

Comment: @hitesh, not really sure what needs clarification. this should be marked as the answer as it solves your question. the data("count") has the number you are trying to keep track of, all you have to do is do something with that value

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript

```
function CountOnFormSubmitEvent(form_id, _callback_)
{
    var that = this, count = 0, callback = _callback_;

    var form = document.getElementById(form_id);
    if(form === null) { return null; }

    var reset = function(){
        count = 0;  
    };

    form.addEventListener("submit", function(evt){
        callback(evt, ++count, reset);
    }, false);
}

var counter = new CountOnFormSubmitEvent("myForm", function(event, count, reset_callback){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(count >= 4)
    {
        alert("Too many clicks !");
        reset_callback();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3snmg7bt/

I hope it will help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Initially, add a id to your button as 'clicked-0'. Now do it as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form#Submit").submit(function(){
         var clicks = $(this).attr('id').replace('clicked-','');
         clicks = clicks+1;
         alert("No. of times clicked:"+clicks);
         $(this).attr('id','clicked-'+clicks);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $("form#Submit").submit(function(){
         count++;
         console.log(count); //for instance
    });
});
```

count is defined in the anonymous function that is executed on domready. It thus is only available inside that aonymous function (and ofcourse to everything inside it, e.g. the submit function)

**EDIT**

You can test that it is not in the global scope:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $("form#Submit").submit(function(){
         count++;
         console.log(count); //for instance
         console.log(window.count); //undefined
    });
});
```

Comment: but it is still global variable

Comment: euhm. noo... Maybe define 'global'